# Yii2 - Creating 'AND (condition1 OR condition2)' in Query Builder

Tags: yii2, query-builder

This is my designated query:

```
SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `category`='2' AND (`a` > 100 OR `b` > 200)
```

I can use following code:

```
$query->andWhere('a>100 OR b>200');
```

but I want to fully use QueryBuilder like this:

```
$query->andWhere([
   $query->orWhere('>', 'a', 100),
   $query->orWhere('>', 'b', 200)
]);
```

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query
    ->where(['and', 'category = :category', ['or', 'a > :a', 'b > :b']])
    ->addParams([
        ':category' => 2,
        ':a' => 100,
        ':b' => 200
    ]);
```

[More info](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-query-builder.md#operator-format-)